# Nonorasu - A Nonogram-Kakurasu Hybrid

Tags: grid-deduction, nonogram

Both [Kakurasu](https://brainbashers.com/kakurasuhelp.asp) (or see [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102147/q-what-kind-of-logic-puzzle-would-you-like-a-yes) for a description) and [Nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) puzzles require the solver to shade certain cells in a square grid by providing clues to the shading pattern of individual rows and columns. In a Nonogram, the solver is given the lengths of the shaded segments in the row/column, while in a Kakurasu the solver is given the sum of the shaded squares, where each row/column is given a value for the sum, usually increasing digits starting from 1.

This puzzle is a hybrid of these two approaches: the columns are clued with Nonogram style clues, while the rows are clued with Kakurasu sums...the column values for the Kakurasu sums are given across the bottom, colored red for visual distinction only. The solution is a shading of some cells in the grid that satisfies all clues. I hope you enjoy!

[image: Grid]

**Text Version**

```
    1     1           1
  1 1 3 2 1 1   1   1 1
  1 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 4 3 2
  1 4 1 1 1 1 5 2 2 1 2
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 54
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 17
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 32
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 26
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 36
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 60
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 47
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 27
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 20
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 22
 -----------------------
 | | | | | | | | | | | | 36
 -----------------------
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 1
                    0 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> [image: sol]

Steps:

> I will name the rows and columns by the clue numbers. There is only ambiguity for r36, but it should be clear from the pictures.

> Start with r60 and apply usual nonogram rule to c7.
>
>  [image: s1]

> If r17c9 (the red circle) is shaded, then we reach the following situation, where r54 is now problematic.
>
>  [image: s2]

> Therefore r17c9 is not shaded, and r54 gives some more information.
>
>  [image: s3]

> Nonogram logic.
>
>  [image: s4]

> Analyzing all possibilities of r32, we see that r32c5 must be shaded and r32c10 must be non-shaded.
>
>  [image: s5]

> Nonogram logic tells us that r32c8 is not shaded, thus r32 determined.
>
>  [image: s6]

> Analyzing r26, we see that r26c8 must be shaded.
>
>  [image: s7]

> Analyzing r47...
>
>  [image: s8]

> Nonogram logic...
>
>  [image: s9]

> Now r26 is determined and some more nonogram...
>
>  [image: s10]

> Now r36c7 is shaded and hence r36 is determined.
>
>  [image: s11]

> The rest is easy and we get the result.
>
>  [image: sol]

Finally, I tried to paint the resulting picture. It doesn't look like anything, though...

> [image: sp]

Comment: Matches my solution! Looking forward to the logic.

Comment: Looks great! I know nonograms usually have a pretty picture at the end, but I was trying to focus on creating interesting deductions instead...sorry for missing that payoff. In recompense, a checkmark!